# Copy and paste to each new worksheet with formatting and formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I need your assistance on VBA code to Copy Paste to each new worksheet with formatting and formulas using the range method.
Here are 2 variations of what I have. One copies and pastes with format but pastes as values and the other retained the formula but not the format. 
Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

1. This keeps the format but paste as value

   ```
   rngHeader.Copy Destination:=.Range("A4")
   res.Copy Destination:=.Range("A5")
   ```
2. This keeps formula but loses the formatting

   ```
   .Range("A4").Resize(, rngHeader.Columns.Count).Formula = rngHeader.Formula
   .Range("A5").Resize(res.Rows.Count, res.Columns.Count).Formula = res.Formula
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paste it all, try:

```
res.Copy
.Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll '~~> paste to destination
```

**Edit:1** Based on comments, if it is a non-contiguous cell then you'll have to loop or use brute force.

1. Brute Force

   ```
   With Sheet1 '~~> change to your actual sheet
       res.Copy
       .Range("A4").Select '~~> you have to select the destination
       .Paste '~~> use Sheet.Paste method
   End With
   ```
2. Looping

   ```
   Dim c As Range, i As Long: i = 0

   With Sheet1
       For Each c In res
           c.Copy
           .Range("A4").Offset(i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
           i = i + 1
       Next
   End With
   ```

Comment: @L2, thanks for your input. I tried that and it gave an error saying the PasteSpecial code cannot be used on multiple selections.

Comment: res is set as:    Set res = .Offset(1).Resize(lastrow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Comment: @GoldO Ah, you never mentioned that it is non-contiguous cell. Added a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: I got the desired result by using both of my codes above. The first one copied over everything with the format and then I used the 2nd one on top of that to get the formulas. Thanks for your help @L42

Comment: @GoldO Glad it did! :)